# How to remove TBS WMP plug-in?

Tags: windows-vista, virus, malware

How to remove TBS WMP plug-in? It seems like a malware installed on my computer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if this plugin has a uninstaller?

In the WMP Options dialog (Menu>Tools>Options) there should be a Plug-ins tab where some of the plugins can be turned off. If it is not listed there you can remove it from the registry, plugins are listed in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Plugins
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\UIPlugins
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Plugins
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\UIPlugins
```